# Given an array which may contain duplicates, print all elements and their frequencies

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Input

```
temperoryArray=(10 20 20 10 10 20 5 20)
```

Output

```
10 3
20 4
5  1
```

Comment: This feels like you just want us to do your homework for you. Have you tried anything? What went wrong? Can you use tools like `sort` or `uniq` or must this all be done in bash?

Answer (score 2):

The output columns are the opposite of what you desire but:

```
printf '%s\n' "${temperoryArray[@]}" | sort | uniq -c
      3 10
      4 20
      1 5
```

If you really want to flip them you could do:

```
printf '%s\n' "${temperoryArray[@]}" | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
10 3
20 4
5 1
```